# Change the Button contents in XAML on trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm trying to make a template that will change a `Button`'s background as well as the color of it's `TextBlock`. I tried the following XAML in my template, but it just makes the button dissapear on mouseover. Is there any way to change the properties of a buttons contents on triggers?

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border 
                        x:Name="Border"  
                        CornerRadius="0" 
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="{x:Null}"
                        BorderBrush="#FF404040" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                          <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="TextBlock">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButton">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        BorderBrush="#FF404040">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="50" Content="Lalala" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Background="Brown" Foreground="Green" BorderThickness="2"></Button>
```

1. You're missing the `ContentPresenter`, responsible for visualizing the `Content` property of the `Button`.
2. To set the foreground you can use `TextBlock.Foreground` attached property.
3. [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) has always been very usefull to me :)

Comment: Side question, if my Button's content is a StackPanel with a TextBlock inside of it, would I just use StackPanel.TextBlock.Foreground instead of TextBlock.Foreground?

Comment: Unfortunately `TextBlock.Foreground` won't work on more complex scenarios (just default one). `StackPanel.TextBlock.Foreground` won't work either. When you have more complex content I think the styling should be done on the context itself and not on the template.